# Magento 2 custom module select query doesn't work

Tags: module, database, collection, magento2.2.2, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `secondTable`.* FROM `table_one` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `table_two` AS `secondTable` 
ON main_table.blog_id = secondTable.blog_id 
WHERE (store_id = '3') OR (store_id = '0');
```

Now take this query and run in CLI it Works perfect it gives all the data you need but in magento it doens't. I Think there is something preventing it but not sure. So `blog_id` are in both tables could be why it isn't returning so if it is how could I add alias for the columns `blog_id` for both tables?

UPDATE:

**index.php:**

```
public function getBlogs(sort)
    {
        if (is_null($this->blogs)) {
            $this->blogs = $this->blogCollectionFactory->create()
                ->setOrder(empty($sort)?'position':$sort, 'ASC');
             $this->blogs->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)->where('secondTable.store_id = ?', $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())->orwhere('secondTable.store_id = ?', 0);
             echo $this->blogs->getSelect();
        }
        return $this->blogs;
    }
```

[image]

So if I don't add the last statement `->orwhere('secondTable.store_id = ?', 0)` then it works but I need to return everything including those that belongs to store_id=0 hence why added but in magento doesn't like it;

**index.phtml:**

```
print_r(get_class_methods($block->getBlogs('position')));
print_r($block->getBlogs('position')->getSelect());
die;
```

Comment: Does `store_id` column available in both the tables ?

Comment: @ Abdul Pathan No Only second table

Comment: Could you please update the Magento code you are using to run the query. Also show the error it throws if any.

Comment: @AbdulPathan No error the page returns but without items I supposed getCollection() is returning array()

Comment: It would be helpful if you put your Magento code as well in the question.

Comment: @AbdulPathan Update hope it help you to help me!